# Use Angular UI Bootstrap to make a Carousel Form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could someone build me an example ui.bootstrap carousel that has a manual button for sliding, and include two `div`s of content? I cannot seem to figure out how to use carousels from just their [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

So far all that I have is the following. (*showing just the controller and .html for cleanliness*)

**Controller**

```
app.controller('RegisterController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };

        $scope.myInterval = 5000; // I don't want timed-sliding. Only manual
        var slides = $scope.slides = [];
        $scope.addSlide = function () {
            slides.push({

            });
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            $scope.addSlide();
        }

});
```

**Registration.html**

```
<div>
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <div>{{slide.content}}</div>
        </slide>
        <button>Next</button>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

If someone could show me a basic example which includes the two following `div`s that'd be awesome!

**slide 1**

```
<div>
   Name: <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**slide 2**

```
<div>
   Password <input type="password" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve, the `carousel` might not be suitable for your requirement. In that case, like @donnanicolas has said, it would be better to roll your own implementation.

But regardless of whether it is suitable for your requirement or not, here is a super basic example that you have asked for:

```
<carousel interval="-1">
  <slide active="activeState[0]">
    <div>
      Name: <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </slide>
  <slide active="activeState[1]">
    <div>
      Password: <input type="password" />
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="nextSlide()">Next</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.activeState = [true, false];

$scope.nextSlide = function () {
  var activeIndex = $scope.activeState.indexOf(true);
  if (activeIndex >= $scope.activeState.length - 1) {
    return; // already reached the last slide
  }

  $scope.activeState[activeIndex] = false;
  $scope.activeState[activeIndex + 1] = true;
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/44TMU4I9Di3vQKjkexBf?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I am also not sure if I shall implement it just yet, but this is very helpful regardless. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using angular ui bootstrap for this, their carousel is a **directive**, it should have NO relation with a controller. You should make your own code. You could take a look at their code to see how the calculate sizes and all of that.

**EDIT**
As is says in the comments there are no event in angular ui bootstrap.

Comment: FYI, unlike the original from bootstrap, there is no events in the ui-bootstrap's carousel.